# Android and SOAP Webservice

Tags: android, soap, wsdl, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to interface my Android application with my SOAP webservices, and I get unexpected results...

Soap services are working fine, they've been tested with SoapUI, WSDL is valid. 
I'm using ksoap2 lib version 1.6.1

Here is my calling code :

```
    try {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("prop1", 1);
        request.addProperty("prop2", "FR");
        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject objetSOAP = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        Log.e("TESTSOAP", objetSOAP.getProperty(0).toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("androidHttpTransport.requestDump", androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("androidHttpTransport.responseDump", androidHttpTransport.responseDump);


    }
```

I got an exception at the "call" method, wich is :

```
03-13 17:31:05.791: W/System.err(6020):     at 03-13 17:30:19.901: W/System.err(5976):            org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG .... @2:402 in java.io.InputStreamReader@46294968)
```

What is weird is that if I use the requestDump to get the sent envelope in SoapUI to try it out, it works perfectly fine. I got the expected result. But the responseDump is actually returning me the wsdl file, and not the result. Just like if the wsdl was called fine, but not the method i'm trying to invoke.

Anyone got an idea on why ? And maybe how to correct it ?

Thanks !

Comment: try envelope.dotNet = true...

Comment: tried it.. didn't change anything :(

Comment: change your transport statement with this line...AndroidHttpTransport transport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URI);

Comment: Try using a recent version of ksoap2. What type of object is returning your web service? (String, int, complex ...?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn it, finally found a solution (months after!)
Apparently,

```
   androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

Should point not to the wsdl, but to the php file.

Comment: Dear Ours,    

can you please tell me what do u mean by Should point not to the wsdl, but to the php file. ?? i am facing the same poblem

Answer (score 0):

class soapDemo extends AsyncTask 
        {

```
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        private final String SOAP_ACTION = "YOUR_PATH";
        private final String METHOD_NAME = "METHOD_NAME";
        private final String NAMESPACE = "NAMESPACE (for ex.http://)";
        private final String URL = "URL";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        this.dialog.setMessage("data Loading");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) 
    {

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        Request.addProperty("KEY",  "VALUE");
        Request.addProperty("KEY",  "VALUE");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try 
    {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        System.out.println("response"+response);
        int  Count = response.getPropertyCount();
        list= new String[Count];    


        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
           list[i] = response.getPropertyAsString(i).toString();
        }

    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
    exc=true;
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {

        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) 
        {
           this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
        if(exc)
        {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            spinner();
            exc=false;
        }
     }
    }

    public void spinner()
    {
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int pos, long id) 
            {
            // your code
            }

      });
    }
```